# How to get the URL parameters after redirecting using javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, window.location

After replacign the location with new parameters, the page after loaded doesn't get the paramaters value, despite there are values in the parameters 
the used code is :

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return
    decodeURI((RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search) || [, null])[1]);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sub").slideUp();
    var div = getURLParameter("div");
    var ddl = getURLParameter("ddl");
    alert(div);
    //            alert("ManageTrainingNeeds.aspx?div=" + div + "&ddl=" + ddl);
    // $("#" + div).slideDown();
    //  $("#ddlObjectiveGroup").val("'" + ddl + "'");      
});
$(".btnAddSub").live("click", function () {
    var diva = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr("id");
    var ddl = $("#ddlObjectiveGroup option:selected").val();
    window.location.replace("ManageTrainingNeeds.aspx?div=" + diva + "&ddl=" + ddl);
});
```

this `alert(div);` return `undefined`.. despite the `div` vairable in click event has a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding the parameters and also canceling the default action in the click event:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search) || [, null])[1]);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var div = getURLParameter('div');
    var ddl = getURLParameter('ddl');
    alert(div + ' ' + ddl);
});

$('.btnAddSub').live('click', function () {
    var diva = encodeURIComponent($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id'));
    var ddl = encodeURIComponent($('#ddlObjectiveGroup').val());
    window.location.replace('/ManageTrainingNeeds.aspx?div=' + diva + '&ddl=' + ddl);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fiddling with the URLs yourself, you could use a library for the job - such as [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/). (sorry for the self-promo)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var search = URI().search(true);
    alert(search.div + ' ' + search.ddl);
});

$('.btnAddSub').live('click', function (e) {
    var uri = URI('/ManageTrainingNeeds.aspx');
    uri.search({
        diva: $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id'),
        ddl: $('#ddlObjectiveGroup').val()
    });
    window.location.href = uri.toString();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```